# Sharing contents on linked with c# WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, linkedin-api

i have create a c# WCF data service which share a contents to facebook, twitter and on emails now i want to share the contents on linkedin also is there any **C# linkedin API** available for sharing contents on linked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the ans ,
we can share contents on linkedin with the help of below URL

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&ro=false&trk=bookmarklet&title=url=

for example-
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&ro=false&trk=bookmarklet&title=Pengumail%20announces%20Send%20Yesterday%20feature&url=http://pengumail.com/features.html#SendYesterday

Answer (score 1):

Usually the best place to look for API's from another service/website is...at that service/website :)

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&q=LinkedIn+API&oq=LinkedIn+API&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=257169l262046l0l262597l17l15l2l0l0l0l221l1823l0.11.2l13) turned up this:  [LinkedIn Developer Network](http://developer.linkedin.com/)

I'd start looking there, and if you don't find what you're looking for expand your search to see if there are other options - but chances are pretty good this will meet your needs: [Share Button LinkedIn Developer Network](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-button)